# Get bounding indices of non-unique words in a string

Tags: java, python, string, clojure

Suppose I have the following string:

```clj
 (def strg "apple orange apple")
```

I'd like the bounding indices of each non-unique word in the string.   So the first occurrence of apple should have the bounding indices  (0,4) while the second occurence of apple should have the bounding indices (13, 17).

One approach that I've been playing with is to first store the indices of each character in the string and, then, for each index n,  identify word boundaries by looking for a space at n-1 (yes, this misses beginning-of-string words). If this condition has been met, iterate thru next k characters until another space is hit---the character at the position immediately before the space is the second bounding index. The first part of this (failed) code is

```clj
 (for [ch strg] 
      (let [indx  (int  (.indexOf  strg  (str ch)))] 
           (cond  (= (subs ch indx-1 ) " " ) 
           continue with rest of above-described code logic
```

Any ideas  (Clojure, Java, or Python is fine) would be appreciated

Comment: What do you do with the sub-strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be more typical for Clojure/Java to use indices of the starting character and one after the ending character, so `[0, 5]` and `[13, 18]` instead. Java's [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) will return the start and end of each match in this manner.

```clj
(def strg "apple orange apple")

(defn re-indices [re s] 
  (let [m (re-matcher re s)] 
    ((fn step [] 
       (when (. m find) 
         (cons [(. m start) (. m end)] (lazy-seq (step))))))))

(re-indices #"\S+" strg)
;=> ([0 5] [6 12] [13 18])
```

And `subs` will use them appropriately

```clj
(->> (re-indices #"\S+" strg)
     (group-by (partial apply subs strg)))
;=> {"apple" [[0 5] [13 18]], "orange" [[6 12]]}
```

From here you can filter out only those substring keys with more than one indices pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: import re

In [13]: def find_ind(word, s):
             return [(w.start(), w.end() - 1) for w in re.finditer(word, s) if s.count(word) > 1]

In [14]: find_ind("apple",s)
        [(0, 4), (13, 17)]

In [15]: find_ind("orange",s)
        []
```

Using python and [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer)

*Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string*